# How to do a GET to IP address of site with Postman

Tags: get, ip, postman

I have a website hosted on a Windows Server that runs in IIS. I'm trying to do a GET request with Postman using the IP address of the server rather than the site URL.

Why does something this work: `http://testsite.com/Callback?parameter=test`

But this doesn't: `http://{site IP address}/Callback?parameter=test`

Comment: Do you need to specify the port?

Comment: @DannyDainton thanks for the suggestion.. without the port I was getting a 404 and with the port Postman says 'Could not get any response'.

Comment: Maybe also try the `SSL Certificate Validation` in the `Settings`(Found in the top right of the native app) as I've had issues with this in the past when working locally.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `Host: testsite.com` header. The site *might* require that to work.

(if you can hit the URL in a web browser using the IP, then this isn't relevant)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you please check this setting in postman:

"Use Postman proxy" it should be set to No.

I use postman with this setting and localhost uri's work well for me..